# How to pass points vector as function parameter in cocos2d-x v3?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

The thing I am trying to achieve is to pass points vector as parameter of a function.

```
cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Point> p;


    p.pushBack(Point(5,5));
    p.pushBack(Point(19,30));
.........
.........
//Function Call 
this->passArray(p);

//function definition
void GameLayer::passArray(const cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Point> &p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
    std::cout<<p.at(i).x;
    }
}
```

but it do not work. As array is not supported by v3, how can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectors have changed in v3.0
Have to check this blog :
http://dev.bunnyhero.org/2014/01/cocos2d-x-30-beta-the-new-vector-class/

And, if all fails, you can always use std::vector

Also, Class Point is not inherited from CCNode and does not have basic functionality to be used with cocos2d::vector.